# Can't log in beaglebone as root

Tags: authentication, beagleboneblack, yocto

I just built the yocto project for beaglebone black by running `bitbake core-image-minimal`

I have successfully loaded kernel and rootfs up using **tftp** and **nfs**.

But I just can't figure out how to login as **root** through the serial port.

After I type `root` and enter, it just prints things like this:

> beaglebone login: root
>
> login: can
>
> Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro) 1.8+snapshot-20150726 beaglebone /dev/ttyO0
>
> beaglebone login: root
>
> login: can
>
> Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro) 1.8+snapshot-20150726 beaglebone /dev/ttyO0
>
> beaglebone login:

Can anyone please give any hint what might have gone wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add  "debug-tweaks" to your extra image feature.
This disable password for root user.

Just add the following line in your local.conf file:

```
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += " debug-tweaks "
```

You will then be able to log in as root, without any password.

Comment: Hi John, I have that enabled in my conf/local.conf. And I was trying to login in serial port instead of ssh.

Comment: In fact, 'debug-tweaks' must disable root password for both of serial port and ssh. Also make sure your SERIAL_CONSOLE variable point to the correct tty. to make sure debug-tweaks is really aplied, try to connect to your system over ssh, and check that password is not asked.

Comment: follow what john said..It'll work .... this is from my local.conf file ..."#  "debug-tweaks"   - make an image suitable for development
#                     e.g. ssh root access has a blank password"

Comment: Hi, I have added this line on my `local.conf`, I noticed only `core-image-minimal-xxx.testdata.json` get updated, the image and the rootfs are not updated, is that expected ?

Answer (score 0):

I put exactly the same kernel and rootfs to sdcard and it works! It must be my NFS setup.

Follow up - It is some folders in my rootfs have been changed to the wrong permission somehow... After removing everything and extracting modules-beaglebone.tgz and core-image-minimal-beaglebone.tar.bz2 to the rootfs, I could finally log in as root!

Thanks to all you guys!